# Cannot assign value of type '[String : AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Xcode 7 and swift I get this error when run my app in my iPhone:

> Cannot assign value of type `[String : AnyObject]` to type `UIImage?`

```
   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
                imgview.image = info
                [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as?UIImage;
                dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot split `[]` operator onto a separate line in Swift: square brackets need to be on the same line as the dictionary being dereferenced. Also don't forget to dismiss and release the `picker`.

```
picker.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
picker.release()
imgview.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
```

Since Swift does not use mandatory semicolons to break down statements, you need to pay more attention to what goes onto which line. Your code is interpreted like this:

- Assign `info` to `imgview.image`
- Cast an array that consists of `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` to `UIImage`

Obviously, this is not the effect that you were trying to get. Moving square brackets to the same line as `info` will fix this problem.

Comment: Look at the code in the question again (I made the same mistake). The dictionary lookup is broken onto two lines.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for pointing this out, I did not realize that the lines were related until you said so.

Answer (score 0):

`info` is a dictionary, which is what `[String : AnyObject]` means. The keys of the dictionary are String's and the values can be any object.  Yet, you wrote:

```
imgview.image = info
```

So, you assigned some dictionary to `imgview.image`, yet imgview.image is of type UIImage optional.  Instead, you need something like:

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
imageView.image = image
```